# Step Functions: how to handle custom errors from activity workers?

Tags: aws-step-functions

I understand that AWS Step Functions support customized error handling for AWS Lambda Functions, but is there support for customized errors from activity workers (sendTaskFailure)?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is ! No matter the activity worker you can define a `Catch` property for your Step, handling different customized errors, see [Amazon States Language Errors](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-errors.html) and [Handling Error Conditions Using a State Machine](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-handling-error-conditions.html).

You just need to set your error name properly in the SendTaskFailure `name` property, see [SendTaskFailure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_SendTaskFailure.html) and use the names in your different `Catch` statements / cases.